# Can we define a sphere around us that would contain a star in any direction?

Tags: stars, density

Can we find a radius R so that in any direction around us (earth), in straight line, we can find at least one star at a distance shorter than R ?

If so, do we have an estimate ?

Or do we know that the universe density is -already- too low ?

Comment: Can the "us" be anywhere in the universe ?

Comment: If I'm inside the sun (or any other star) that is easy! In an infinite universe, it is doable. In our (apparently) finite universe, it may not be possible.

Comment: Yeah we'll say the center of the sphere is earth, but I guess "anywhere outside of stars" would be equivalent?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27s_paradox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume what you mean is, out to what radius would we have to go in order for every sightline to intercept a star? Otherwise there is no sensible definition of "direction".

There are about $10^{22}$ stars in the observable universe out to a comoving radius of order 40 billion light years (give or take, and using the [comoving radius of the observable universe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe)) because the first stars took a little while to form.

If we assume a homogeneous universe (it isn't in time, but I'll let that slide), the stellar density is $n=4\times 10^{-11}$ per cubic light year. The [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path#Derivation) before a sightline hits a star is $\sim (n\sigma)^{-1}$, where $\sigma$ is the average cross-sectional area of a star. Let's make all stars the same size as the Sun (a small fraction are much larger, but most are about half the size), then $\sigma \sim 1.5\times 10^{18}$ m$^2$.

Thus the mean free path before a sightline intersects a star is $\sim 10^{24}$ light years.

Could our local "density enhancement" (aka the Galaxy) play any role. Well the local stellar density is much higher at 0.004 per cubic light year. This gives a "local mean free path" of a mere $\sim 10^{16}$ light years.

So the answer is no, and you would need a much older universe to allow you to "see" stars $10^{24}$ light years away.

Note here that I have had to choose a definition of what is meant by radius and I have chosen the comoving radius.

Comment: Does it make sense to speak of radius over such distances with the universe expanding and distance not being a relativistic invariant?

Comment: Possibly this should be a comment to the OP. Anyway, I have chosen to use comoving distance which is invariant. @Conifold

Comment: Thks ! Do you have a link for the mean free path formula ? I saw it in 1D on wikipedia, it might be an evidence but I'm confused about how to apply it to 3D.

Comment: @GhislainBugnicourt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path#Derivation  I am not sure what you mean by 3D. Beams of light are 1D.